# ncclient timed out when using junos_vlan

Tags: networking, ansible

I use ansible for network automation. 
Usually everything works great, but when trying to create vlan at a particular Juniper switch, I get `ncclient timed out while waiting for an rpc reply` error. I use `junos_vlan` module.

I tried extending the timeout periods at `ansible.cfg`, switching `ansible_connection` from `network_cli` to `netconf` and so on, but none of that helped.

Can something be done from either server's or switch's side?

I read about a guy finding a workaround editing the module file:
[Ansible, Juniper CLI commands. Timeout Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863701/ansible-juniper-cli-commands-timeout-error)

Can I reach a desired effect with the same approach?

I use `ansible 2.8.1` and `python 3.6.3`. The device has  `JUNOS 14.1X53-D47.3` firmware.

Any suggestions?

Here is the output of the failure:

```
TASK [Setting vlan description and giving vlanID] **********************************************

task path: /opt/ansible/roles/juniper/tasks/add_vlan_sw.yml:2

META: noop

META: noop

<x.x.x.x> ESTABLISH NETCONF SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: Ansible on PORT 22 TO x.x.x.x

<x.x.x.x> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root

<x.x.x.x> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-233162pe2oyh4/ansible-tmp-1565773542.046394-83274056275477 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1565773542.046394-83274056275477="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-233162pe2oyh4/ansible-tmp-1565773542.046394-83274056275477 `" ) && sleep 0'

Using module file /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/network/junos/junos_vlan.py

<x.x.x.x> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-233162pe2oyh4/tmpyr3gfpgt TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-233162pe2oyh4/ansible-tmp-1565773542.046394-83274056275477/AnsiballZ_junos_vlan.py

<x.x.x.x> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-233162pe2oyh4/ansible-tmp-1565773542.046394-83274056275477/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-233162pe2oyh4/ansible-tmp-1565773542.046394-83274056275477/AnsiballZ_junos_vlan.py && sleep 0'

<x.x.x.x> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-233162pe2oyh4/ansible-tmp-1565773542.046394-83274056275477/AnsiballZ_junos_vlan.py && sleep 0'

<x.x.x.x> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-233162pe2oyh4/ansible-tmp-1565773542.046394-83274056275477/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'

The full traceback is:

WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.

File "/tmp/ansible_junos_vlan_payload_a3tXYK/ansible_junos_vlan_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/network/junos/junos.py", line 204, in unlock_configuration

response = conn.unlock()

File "/tmp/ansible_junos_vlan_payload_a3tXYK/ansible_junos_vlan_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/network/common/netconf.py", line 76, in __rpc__

return self.parse_rpc_error(to_bytes(rpc_error, errors='surrogate_then_replace'))

File "/tmp/ansible_junos_vlan_payload_a3tXYK/ansible_junos_vlan_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/network/common/netconf.py", line 108, in parse_rpc_error

raise ConnectionError(rpc_error)



fatal: [chi-leafsw06]: FAILED! => {

"changed": false,

"invocation": {

"module_args": {

"active": true,

"aggregate": null,

"description": "Client-100001-dedicated-network",

"filter_input": null,

"filter_output": null,

"host": null,

"interfaces": null,

"l3_interface": null,

"name": "vlan777",

"password": null,

"port": null,

"provider": null,

"ssh_keyfile": null,

"state": "present",

"timeout": null,

"transport": null,

"username": null,

"vlan_id": 777

}

},

"msg": "ncclient timed out while waiting for an rpc reply."

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A guy has offered me a solution in here and I thought this might affect more of you (https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/cq7joa/help_ncclient_timed_out_while_waiting_for_rpc/)

What helped me was actually a suggestion to reduce the version of ncclient in my Ansible server from 0.6.6 to 0.6.4 and extend timeout values in ansible.cfg to at least 120.

So I am saved. Thanks!